# Rails i18n coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Is there a tool (or built-in way) to see if a given translation entry is no longer referenced?  Even a "mechanical" way would be helpful, meaning something which runs the test suite and reports which i18n entries were and were not hit.  (I suppose it could report which translations are missing, too, but that's not what I'm after for the time being.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) gem has what you're looking for as it can find missing and unused translations. It also provides you with a spec template that will fail your suite if any locales have missing or unused translations (see [Installation section on the README](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks#installation)).

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be what I want.  I wonder how this handles things like this, though: i18n_base = 'root.branch'; I18n.t("#{i18n_base}.leaf")

Comment: Looks like the documentation says: "By default, dynamic keys such as t "cats.#{cat}.name" are not recognized. I encourage you to mark these with i18n-tasks-use hints."